# ERD vs UML association - erd being constrained more?

Tags: database-design, uml, entity-relationship, diagram

In an [article](http://www.tdan.com/view-special-features/8457)
 David C. Hay, I found the following:

In one sense a UML association is equivalent to an entity/relationship relationship, but a

> relationship in an entity/relationship model is more constrained in
>   what it can represent than is an object-oriented association.
>   Specifically, as will be described below, each relationship is a pair
>   of assertions about the nature of the business. It is not simply
>   recognition that two things are somehow associated with each other.

But it does not explain (or I do not get it) how is ERD relationship more constraained when compared to UML?

Answer (score 1):

I would assert that the article in question is incorrect an that in fact it is not trie to say 'recognition that two things are somehow associated with each other'. Many people use ERD and class diagrams interchangeably